# What "cache" is being used in sqlhelperparametercache

Tags: c#, sql, .net, caching, ado.net

I have been trying to determine what cache is being used when you call SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet. I think it may be the SQL SErver Execution plan cache but I am not sure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580.aspx

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on MSDN. Any ideas about this ancient object?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the SQL Server plan cache; it is just an in-process hashtable of the signature of the stored procedures that the DAAB is aware of. Note that it is very unusual to see the DAAB still in use these days.

Comment: Yes, it is unusual. This is pretty old legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of this [source code](https://github.com/nuxleus/flexwikicore/blob/master/SqlProvider/SqlHelperParameterCache.cs#L32) that looks to be a mirror the original, it would appear that they are using a static `Hashtable`.  The cache wouldn't live beyond the AppPool lifecycle as a result.

```
private static Hashtable paramCache = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to start checking github for these old MS libraries.

Comment: Happy to help!  There's a few "gems" still holding on out there on GitHub :)